# Linq select items up until next occurrence

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need to filter the following list to return all items beginning with the first item that starts with "Group", up until, but not including the next item that starts with "Group" (or the up until the last item).

```
List<string> text = new List<string>();
text.Add("Group Hear It:");
text.Add("    item: The Smiths");
text.Add("    item: Fernando Sor");
text.Add("Group See It:");
text.Add("    item: Longmire");
text.Add("    item: Ricky Gervais Show");
text.Add("    item: In Bruges");
```

After filtering, I want to have the following items in the first grouping:

> ```
> "Group Hear It:"
> "    item: The Smiths"
> "    item: Fernando Sor"
> ```

And the following items in the second grouping:

> ```
> "Group See It:"
> "    item: Longmire"
> "    item: Ricky Gervais Show"
> "    item: In Bruges"
> ```

This doesn't work because I'm filtering the list in the first where to exclude the "item:" items... Am I close with **TakeWhile**, or way off?

```
var group = text.Where(t => t.StartsWith("Group ")))
   .TakeWhile(t => t.ToString().Trim().StartsWith("item"));
```

Comment: It would make more sense to create a data structure that's appropriate to your domain rather than filtering a list based on keywords.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like Jeff Mercado's but doesn't pre-process entire enumerable:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> ChunkOn<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> startChunk)
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();

        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if(startChunk(item) && list.Count > 0)
            {
                yield return list;
                list = new List<T>();
            }

            list.Add(item);
        }

        if(list.Count > 0)
        {
            yield return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Use like:

```
List<string> text = new List<string>();
text.Add("Group Hear It:");
text.Add("    item: The Smiths");
text.Add("    item: Fernando Sor");
text.Add("Group See It:");
text.Add("    item: Longmire");
text.Add("    item: Ricky Gervais Show");
text.Add("    item: In Bruges");

var chunks = text.ChunkOn(t => t.StartsWith("Group"));
```

Comment: I haven't tried each solution offered, but I like this one a lot.  It's simple, doesn't have a lot of overhead, and is clean and neat to call using the extension.  I didn't know about "yield return <list>" before; that's sweet.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this rather cleanly with the help of a generator.  The generator will keep track of what key is currently in use, something you can't do with a traditional LINQ query without introducing external variables.  You'll just need to decide when the key should change as you go through the collection.  Once you get the key to use for each item, just group them by that key.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TResult>> ConsecutiveGroupBy<TSource, TKey, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, bool> takeNextKey,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        Func<TSource, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        return
            from kvp in AssignKeys(source, takeNextKey, keySelector)
            group resultSelector(kvp.Value) by kvp.Key;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TSource>> AssignKeys<TSource, TKey>(
        IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, bool> takeNextKey,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        var key = default(TKey);
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (takeNextKey(item))
                key = keySelector(item);
            yield return new KeyValuePair<TKey, TSource>(key, item);
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
var lines = new List<string>
{
    "Group Hear It:",
    "    item: The Smiths",
    "    item: Fernando Sor",
    "Group See It:",
    "    item: Longmire",
    "    item: Ricky Gervais Show",
    "    item: In Bruges",
};

var query = lines.ConsecutiveGroupBy(
    line => line.StartsWith("Group"),
    line => line,
    line => line);
```

Comment: +1: Slick.  But may not yield desired results if you hit the same Group name again: this code would lump those results into a single group.

Comment: In that case, a more appropriate key selector would be required which will distinguish the distinct groups with the same keys. e.g., one that will incorporate the index of the key within the collection. The code above doesn't facilitate that scenario as-is, but it should be simple to make that adjustment as needed.

Comment: I like grouping iterators, but I often forget that GroupBy requires a complete enumeration and caching of items in the source before the first group can be returned.

Comment: @Patrick: I could have easily done without it. I only chose to use `GroupBy` here because it was the easiest way to get `IGrouping<>` objects without having to reimplement it. It's a shame the framework designers didn't provide a simple public implementation of a group, it's all internal.

Answer (score 1):

One way is by using a class and using LINQ to get the results from the class:

```
    public class MediaItem {
        public MediaItem(string action, string name) {
            this.Action = action;
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public string Action = string.Empty;

        public string Name = string.Empty;

    }

    List<MediaItem> mediaItemList = new List<MediaItem>();
    mediaItemList.Add(new MediaItem("Group: Hear It", "item: The Smiths"));
    mediaItemList.Add(new MediaItem("Group: Hear It", "item: Fernando Sor"));
    mediaItemList.Add(new MediaItem("Group: See It", "item: Longmire"));
    mediaItemList.Add(new MediaItem("Group: See It", "item: Ricky Gervais Show"));
    mediaItemList.Add(new MediaItem("Group: See It", "item: In Bruges"));

    var results = from item in mediaItemList.AsEnumerable()
                  where item.Action == "Group: Hear It"
                  select item.Name;

    foreach (string name in results) {
        MessageBox.Show(name);
    }
```

Another way is using LINQ by itself:

```
    // Build the list
    List<string> text = new List<string>();
    text.Add("Group Hear It:");
    text.Add("    item: The Smiths");
    text.Add("    item: Fernando Sor");
    text.Add("Group See It:");
    text.Add("    item: Longmire");
    text.Add("    item: Ricky Gervais Show");
    text.Add("    item: In Bruges");
    text.Add("Group Buy It:");
    text.Add("    item: Apples");
    text.Add("    item: Bananas");
    text.Add("    item: Pears");

    // Query the list and create a "table" to work with
    var table = from t in text
                select new {
                    Index = text.IndexOf(t),
                    Item = t,
                    Type = t.Contains("Group") ? "Group" : "Item",
                    GroupIndex = t.Contains("Group") ? text.IndexOf(t) : -1
                };

    // Get the table in reverse order to assign the correct group index to each item
    var orderedTable = table.OrderBy(i => i.Index).Reverse();

    // Update the table to give each item the correct group index
    table = from t in table
            select new {
                Index = t.Index,
                Item = t.Item,
                Type = t.Type,
                GroupIndex = t.GroupIndex < 0 ?
                    orderedTable.Where(
                        i => i.Type == "Group" &&
                        i.Index < t.Index           
                    ).First().Index :
                    t.GroupIndex
            };

    // Get the "Hear It" items from the list
    var hearItItems = from g in table
                      from i in table
                      where i.GroupIndex == g.Index &&
                      g.Item == "Group Hear It:"
                      select i.Item;

    // Get the "See It" items from the list
    var seeItItems = from g in table
                     from i in table
                     where i.GroupIndex == g.Index &&
                     g.Item == "Group See It:"
                     select i.Item;

    // Get the "Buy It" items I added to the list
    var buyItItems = from g in table
                     from i in table
                     where i.GroupIndex == g.Index &&
                     g.Item == "Group Buy It:"
                     select i.Item;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var i = 0;
var groups = text.GroupBy(t => t.StartsWith("Group") ? ++i : i);
```

i holds the number of times we've seen the group condition.  using i++ instead of ++i would let the condition complete a group instead of start it.

Comment: You should *really* avoid LINQ queries that cause side effects like this; it's generally contrary to their design.

Comment: @Servy I wasn't sure it would even work before I tried it. Other than losing a little declarative purity, I don't see the harm.  Is there any worry that the evaluation of the statement would ever change?

Comment: There is no guarantee that the selectors are called in order; you're simply relying on an implementation detail.  Will it change; who knows, that's the idea of an implementation detail.  Could it change while still meeting the method's specs, yes, it most certainly could.

Answer (score 0):

You may need imperative code to do it, I can't think of a LINQ solution.

```
List<List<string>> results = new List<List<string>>();
List<string> currentGroup = null;

foreach (var item in text) 
{
    if (item.StartsWith("Group")) 
    {
        if (currentGroup != null) results.Add(currentGroup);
        currentGroup = new List<string>();
    }
    currentGroup.Add(item);
}
results.Add(currentGroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to do this with clean LINQ and lambda expressions. You could define a delegate method that accesses a boolean flag that is at an outer scope (like on the instance where this is executing) then pass it into the select statement but I think a normal for loop would be better. If you do that you can just note the starting and ending index then extract the range, it would probably be the cleanest solution.